# awk to remove duplicate rows totally based on a particular column value

Tags: sorting, awk, uniq

I got a dataset like:

```
6   AA_A_56_30018678_E  0   30018678    P   A
6   SNP_A_30018678  0   30018678    A   G
6   SNP_A_30018679  0   30018679    T   G
6   SNP_A_30018682  0   30018682    T   G
6   SNP_A_30018695  0   30018695    G   C
6   AA_A_62_30018696_Q  0   30018696    P   A
6   AA_A_62_30018696_G  0   30018696    P   A
6   AA_A_62_30018696_R  0   30018696    P   A
```

I want to remove all the rows if col 4 have duplicates.

I have use the below codes (using sort, awk,uniq and join...) to get the required output, however, is there a better way to do this?

```
sort -k4,4 example.txt | awk '{print $4}' | uniq -u  > snp_sort.txt

join -1 1 -2 4 snp_sort.txt example.txt | awk '{print $3,$5,$6,$1}' > uniq.txt
```

Here is the output

```
SNP_A_30018679  T   G   30018679
SNP_A_30018682  T   G   30018682
SNP_A_30018695  G   C   30018695
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` to filter-out duplicate lines and print those lines which occur exactly once.

```
awk '{k=($2 FS $5 FS $6 FS $4)} {a[$4]++;b[$4]=k}END{for(x in a)if(a[x]==1)print b[x]}' input_file

SNP_A_30018682 T G 30018682
SNP_A_30018695 G C 30018695
SNP_A_30018679 T G 30018679
```

The idea is to:-

1. Store all unique `$4` entries in a an array(`a`) and maintain a counter for that in array `b`
2. Print the array for those entries which occur exactly once.

Answer (score 2):

*Using command substitution*:  First print only `unique` columns in fourth field and then grep those columns.

```
grep "$(echo  "$(awk '{print $4}' inputfile.txt)" |sort |uniq -u)" inputfile.txt
6   SNP_A_30018679  0   30018679    T   G
6   SNP_A_30018682  0   30018682    T   G
6   SNP_A_30018695  0   30018695    G   C
```

Note: add `awk '{NF=4}1'` at the end of the command, if you wist to print first four columns. Of course you can change the number of columns by changing value of `$4` and `NF=4`.

Comment: You still need to sort. Uniq does not do duplicate elimination unless it is consecutive lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{c[$4]++;next} c[$4]<2' file file
6   SNP_A_30018679  0   30018679    T   G
6   SNP_A_30018682  0   30018682    T   G
6   SNP_A_30018695  0   30018695    G   C
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your 'key' is fixed width, then `uniq` has a `-w` to check on it.

```
sort -k4,4 example.txt | uniq -u -f 3 -w 8  > uniq.txt
```

Comment: Hmm, I only got one line out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1; a[$4]=a[$4] $0} END{for(i in a) if(gsub(FS,FS,a[i])==5) print a[i]}' file
6 SNP_A_30018679 0 30018679 T G
6 SNP_A_30018682 0 30018682 T G
6 SNP_A_30018695 0 30018695 G C
```

Catenate to array using `$4` as key. If there are more than 5 field separators, duplicates were catenated and will not be printed.

And yet an another version in awk. It expects the file to be sorted on the fourth field. It won't store all lines in memory<s>, only the keys (this probably could be dealt with also since the key field must be sorted, may be fixed later)</s> and runs in one go:

```
$ cat ananother.awk
++seen[p[4]]==1 && NR>1 && p[4]!=$4 {  # seen count must be 1 and
    print prev                         # this and previous $4 must differ
    delete seen                        # is this enough really?
}
{ 
    q=p[4]                             # previous previous $4 for END
    prev=$0                            # previous is stored for printing
    split($0,p)                        # to get previous $4
} 
END {                                  # last record control
    if(++seen[$4]==1 && q!=$4) 
        print $0
}
```

Run:

```
$ sort -k4,4 file | awk -f ananother.awk
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to achieve this,

`cat file.csv | cut -d, -f3,5,6,1 | sort -u > uniq.txt`